# Sniffing and logging HTTP Traffic through my wireless router

Tags: wireless-router, http, sniffing

I want to sniff traffic going through my wireless router.  The router is provided by my cable company, so I don't want to flash the firmware or anything, so my questions is:  Is there any software or such that I can install on one of the computers on my network, and have it log the HTTP request/response?

Use case: I'm playing a game on my Droid, and I want to see the traffic.

Note: I've already tried setting up a proxy and logging that way.  The game seems to be bypassing my Proxy settings.  Other web traffic will go through my proxy, but not the game's traffic.  I know it's using HTTP, because the game DOES obey the proxy on my friend's iphone (same game).  So setting up a proxy isn't a solution that will work.

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try [Wireshark](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the router you have, unless it allows you to mirror traffic to a port on it, wont let you do this. There are a few ways you could get the traffic:

One, you could setup a hub, not a switch, between the router and the internet and then plug a computer running a packet sniffer like Wireshark into another port on the hub.

Two, you could setup a computer as a gateway between the wireless router and the internet and have all traffic captured using a tool like Wireshark or tcpdump.

Three, setup a new wireless access point that is connected to a hub and have the internet router connected to that hub and a computer connected to that hub running a tool like Wireshark.

Or you could get a router that lets you mirror all traffic to a port on it and plug a computer into that port running a tool like Wireshark.

Sometimes with the right hardware you can capture wireless traffic with Wireshark, if you search the internet there are a few how-tos on how to do this.

You can also look at using something like a [AirPcap](http://www.riverbed.com/us/products/cascade/wireshark_enhancements/airpcap.php)

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I'll try them out and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Setting up wireless access point allowed me to sniff traffic using wireshark.  Thanks!

Comment: I want to buy Hub to capture all traffic but when I searched for it result always shows me SWITCH. will you please send me amazon link to buy HUB not SWITCH.. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to try using [ettercap](http://ettercap.github.io/ettercap/) to sniff your LAN. It has various man-in-the-middle techniques - the most useful on a LAN is the poison ARP Man-In-The-Middle (MITM) approach (assuming your default gateway is 192.168.0.1 - check in your network settings):

```
ettercap -T -M arp:remote /192.168.0.1/ //
```

Generally this should redirect all traffic to the machine that's running ettercap - some devices may manage to sidestep the approach.

If you see an error ("Incorrect number of token (///) in TARGET !!
") then it likely down to the fact that your version of Ettercap is IPv6 enabled (as mentioned [here](https://github.com/Ettercap/ettercap/issues/708)) then you will need to use a slightly modified syntax:

```
ettercap -T -M arp:remote /192.168.0.1// ///
```

Otherwise you'll need to investigate your router and check if it can support port mirroring or link layer bridge modes. The Thomson/Technicolor/Speedtouch routers do support PPP over Ethernet (PPPoE) bridging and some can also do port mirroring.

Comment: This does not work. Ettercap wants another group to be mentioned as target

Comment: This occurs when Ettercap is IPv6 enabled - I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: So In my home I have WIFI router and from that I will connect LAN cable to my LAPTOP, now using ettercap I can capture all traffic, of devices which are connected with WIFI? Please suggest me, so I don't need to buy HUB

Answer (score 1):

[Sniffing HTTP traffic on an Android device](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2014/06/sniffing-http-traffic-on-an-android-device.html)

Answer (score 0):

cheapest fix - use your cable router as a modem, then buy a router that supports mirroring to broadcast your wifi.  (*shut off wifi on the cable modem and hard wire the new router to it for internet - that way all wireless traffic gets captured.)  You can then pick any connected device as the target of your mirror - pick one with decent storage and remember it can only capture when connected to your new router.

Even older routers will support mirroring, and can be had on Ebay for under $20 - but buy a good one, you will want fast wifi at home!